# Shell Script second column is empty ,paste $1 under line

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have data that looks like this:

```
TEST1         
AAAAA MUTUAL  
BBBBB MUTUAL  
CCCCC MUTUAL  
TEST2         
DDDDD SINGLE  
EEEEE SINGLE  
FFFFF SINGLE
```

how do change with Shell script in Unix Solaris  ?

```
AAAAA TEST1   
BBBBB TEST1   
CCCCC TEST1   
DDDDD TEST2   
EEEEE TEST2   
FFFFF TEST2
```

Comment: What have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NF==1{val=$1; next}{ $2 = val}1'  infile

# or

awk 'NF==1{val=$1; next}{ print $1, val }'  infile
```

If you want to try this on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk at the start of the script to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` or `nawk`

Explanation:

- `NF==1{val=$1; next}` if no of fields in record/line/row equal to 1, then save first column in variable `val`
- `next` stop processing further condition, go to next line
- `{ $2 = val}` set saved value to second field ( so lines/records/rows which are not skipped will be modified here )
- `1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, print $0. To know how awk works try, awk '1' infile, which will print all records/lines, whereas awk '0' infile prints nothing. Any number other than zero is true, which triggers the default behavior.

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: If you want to try this on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk at the start of the script to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or /usr/xpg6/bin/awk or nawk

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
nawk '/^TEST/{val=$0;next} {print $1,val}'  Input_file
```